# Magento 2 : Home and Category Page Meta Title / Title are the same

Tags: magento2.4.5, home-page, page-title, meta-title

Is it standard for Magento `home page` and `category page` to use the same `Page Title` and `Meta Title`? I thought page title would be the CMS Page Title (for home page) or Category Name but on mine (v2.4.5) it's just using the Meta Title for both. Can't see an extension overriding it. What is the easiest way to resolve?

Comment: Try to set different Theme and check it will resolve your issue or not?

Comment: Good point. Just tried that but it still uses meta title for both the page and meta title. The only time it seems to use the page title is when meta title is left blank. I'm using the BSS sitemap extension but couldn't see anything in there that might cause this issue, when I disabled it the issue persisted.

Comment: Check the things into private browser one's after disabling the extension.

Comment: No joy. It seems to use the SEO/Meta Title for both <Title> and <Meta name="title"... > when that field is populated, If not it will use the Page (or Category) Name. However I can't get it to use Page/Category Name for the Title and SEO/Meta Title for the Meta Title. I can see both are different in the database. Might try upgrading the Magento version but I'm not optimistic that will do the trick.